Ac/defrost vents troubleshooting
I have 2003 xterra, v6, SE, 2wd, and cant get ac to blow out front vents, defrost knob turns but ac doesnt flow out face vents. I cant seem to find a diagram of this dash area anywhere! So very frustrated!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it this is a mechanical environmental control (not automated)?

Does this help? https://www.manua.ls/nissan/xterra-2003/manual
